# sub menu with using @html.ActionLink

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to have a sub-menu with my MVC application using Razor.

I will like to have a sub-menu call Admin and under it I will have the Category and Product.

_Layout.cshtml

```
 <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Store", "Store", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Admin", "Home")</li>
                        <ul>                                <== I will like to have a sub-menu

                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Category", "Index", "Category")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Product", "Index", "Product")</li>
                        </ul>
                        <li>@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "Cart");}</li>


                     </ul>
 </nav>
```

I can't find the proper easiest way to perform this.

Thanks

I have tried this but it didn't came out as expected.

```
                            <li>
                           <a href="#">Admin</a>
                            <ul class="nested">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Category", "Index", "Category")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Product", "Index", "Product")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

With the following css

```
     #nav ul{
        display : none;
     }
     #nav li:hover > ul{
          display : block;
     }
```

This is coming out like this:

```
    Home   Store     Admin
           Category  Product
                     Cart(0)
```

I want like this

```
   Home  Store   Admin   Cart(0)
             category   Product     <== only if I clicked on admin
```

Here is the full css file for the menu

```
 /* menu
```

----------------------------------------------------------*/
    ul#menu {
      font-size: 1.3em;
      font-weight: 600;
      margin: 0 0 5px;
      padding: 0;
       text-align: right;
    }

```
ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

    ul#menu li a {
        background: none;
        color: #999;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul#menu li a:hover {
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
        display : block;
    }

nav ul{
display : none;
}
nav li:hover > ul{
   display : block;
}
```

Comment: For starters, you cannot have a `<ul>` directly within another `<ul>`. You must wrap your child `<ul>` and any content within a `<ul>` in an `<li>`.

Comment: now it comes out like this  HOME      Store     ADmin                                   ,second line                          Category  Product                      ,Third line                                     Cart(0)

Comment: In your CSS `#nav` should either be `nav` because it is an element type and not an ID, or perhaps you meant `#menu`.

Comment: Checkout [Pure CSS hover list](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic2/horizontal04.htm)

Comment: If click is the desired trigger to display the submenu and not hover than `a:active` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) is the psuedo-class you would use instead of `a:hover`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC, it's purely an HTML/CSS issue, and you would get better help if you did that.  Just get the menu you want with HTML/CSS first, then just replace the text with your ActionLinks.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch  I've changed the title  and I added the full css

Comment: @JeremyCook I added the full css for the menu maybe this is what is causing a problem

Comment: Extending @ErikFunkenbusch suggestion, consider creating a http://jsfiddle.net/ and experimenting with only HTML and CSS. Plus it can automatically tidy up your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the css

```
 ul#menu {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   font-weight: 600;
   margin: 0 0 5px;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: right;
 }

 ul#menu li {
     float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
 }

    ul#menu li a {
        background: none;
        color: #999;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul#menu li a:hover {
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
        display : block;
    }



 ul#submenu { display: none; }
 ul#submenu li { float: none; display: none; }

 ul#menu li:hover ul#submenu
 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 5px;
 }

 ul#menu li:hover ul#submenu li {
     display : block;
```

and the _Layout.cshtml

```
                   <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Accueil", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Magasin", "Magasin", "Home")</li>
                        <li>  <a href="#">Gestion</a>
                            <ul id="submenu" class="nested">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Catégorie", "Index", "Categorie")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Produit", "Index", "Produit")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "Panier");}</li>


                    </ul>
                </nav>
```